# Get the value of an XML element

Tags: python, perl

In the XML example below, how can I can get the value of the `<data>` element? In this case, I would like XML parser to return the value of node as a string which should return

```
This is my first web page<br/><p>test123</p><p>How exciting</p>
```

(i.e. an XML fragment).

I have been trying to use Perl ([`XML::SimpleObject`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimpleObject)) or Python (`miniDOM`). Both of them can only return the text value of the `<data>` element which is `"This is my first web page"`

```
<dataset>
<data>
This is my first web page<br/>
<p>test123</p>
<p>How exciting</p>
</data>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 3):

The 
[`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple)
module is altogether *too* simple and leaves a lot of work to be done by the programmer. I haven't tried 
[`XML::SimpleObject`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimpleObject)
but I would encourage you to use either 
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig)
or
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML),
which are both tried and tested and will cope with all the complexity of the full XML specification.

This sollution uses `XML::Twig`, and simply parses the data, looks up the `<data>` element and prints its contents.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse(\*DATA);

my ($data) = $twig->get_xpath('/dataset/data');
print $data->xml_string;

__DATA__
<dataset>
<data>
This is my first web page<br/>
<p>test123</p>
<p>How exciting</p>
</data>
</dataset>
```

**output**

```
This is my first web page<br/><p>test123</p><p>How exciting</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'EOT');
<dataset>
<data>
This is my first web page<br/>
<p>test123</p>
<p>How exciting</p>
</data>
</dataset>
EOT

my @nodes = $dom->findnodes('/dataset/data');

my $xml_text = $nodes[0]->serialize();

# strip <data> and </data> if you don't want them
$xml_text =~ s{(?: \A <data> | </data> \z )}{}xmsg;

print $xml_text;
```

Comment: $nodes[0]->textContent does not include the XML in the result.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants the "innerHTML" for XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The XML parser is of course "swallowing" the inner elements, as they are completely valid XML.

Either:

1. Fix the encoded XML - if the HTML tags are not supposed to be part of the document structure, they should be encoded suitably.
2. Find the root node of what you want, and **reserialize** the XML to generate text.

Answer (score 0):

use cElementTree lib of python.

```
In [23]: import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

In [24]: myxml="""<dataset>
    ...: <data>
    ...: This is my first web page<br/>
    ...: <p>test123</p>
    ...: <p>How exciting</p>
    ...: </data>
    ...: </dataset>"""

In [25]: page = et.fromstring(myxml)

In [26]: for elem in page.getiterator():
    ...:     if elem.tag=='data':
    ...:         print elem.tag, elem.text
    ...:         for tags in elem.getchildren():
    ...:             print tags.tag, tags.text
    ...:             
data 
This is my first web page
br None
p test123
p How exciting

In [27]:
```

Note: If you are using python 2.7; then use `list(elem)` instead of `elem.getchildren()` and `page.iter()` instead of `page.getiterator()`
further more you can do `elem.attrb` to get dict of xml node's attribute and `elem.tail` to get its tail; http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html